# Formula for generating a series of numbers where probability of a number is inverse to its value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

What would be a formula for generating a series of numbers where the numbers are not exactly random -- their probability depends on their face value. Eg. numbers from 1 to 100, but 1 is twice more likely to appear in the series than 2 and 100 times more likely than 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling.

In your case it amounts to pre computing $H_n = 1+\ldots + 1/n$ for $1\leq n \leq 100$. Then choose $U$ uniform random in $[0,1]$ and return $n$ the only integer such that $H_{n-1}/H_{100} \leq U < H_{n}/H_{100}$.